# Mod security exceptions not working

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, httpd, mod-security

I would like to exclude a directory from mod security.  I have tried everything under the sun in every config file to no avail.  I have put stuff in the vhost file, the crs-setup file, the modsecurity.conf file, the exceptions file in the rules directory, no matter where I put it nothing works.

I have tried a million variations of the below code:

```
    <Directory /www/html/directory/>
            SecRuleInheritance Off
            SecRuleEngine Off
        </Directory>
```

If I remove the directory tags it disables mod security just fine, however within the directory tag nothing works.  I've tried Location and LocationMatch - nothing.  I can't exclude file names either!

Edit: Here is the rule I have added to various places.  I have added it to the top of httpd.conf, crs-setup.conf, modsecurity.conf 000.conf in /rules/ directory.  It unblocks the directory but all images and css which are NOT in that directory are stripped.

SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /directory" "phase:1,id:12345,allow"

Also tried:

SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /directory" "phase:1,id:12345,ctl:ruleEngine=off"

Example url: domain.com/directory/javascript.php?sqlinectioncode

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use those commands within Directory tags.

See this similar question on StackOverflow for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829492/how-to-add-mod-security-exception/

Comment: I configured it like the link said to. I have those rules in a file called 000.conf in my rules directory. I get the following in modsec log file: Message: Warning. Operator GE matched 8 at TX:anomaly_score. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUES‌​T-949-BLOCKING-EVALU‌​ATION.conf"] [line "57"] [id "949110"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score:$

Comment: Looks like if I add that line it shows the page but doesn't allow CSS or images.  But it does allow it.  How can we stop it from blocking the CSS and images?

Comment: It says to put it first as to not block other requests.  I put it first in /rules/ directory.  I tried putting it first in crs-setup.conf file.  Also tried putting it first in mod sec config file.  Not sure whee to put it at this point.

Comment: Can you edit your original question to show the exact rules you’ve added?

Comment: Ok, check it out.